# What is the difference between "urgent" and "critical"?

Tags: meaning, differences

When it comes to "the level of importance", what is the difference between "urgent" and "critical"?

I have my own idea, but I recently came upon a scenario where the relative level of importance was reversed from my expectations. Thus, I'm looking for a standard/objective difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I was looking for exactly this, glad I didn't have to ask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My take is that *urgent* expresses the time frame in which the requirement must be met (but does not speak to the severity of failing to met the requirement), while *critical* expresses the importance of meeting it (but not the deadline for doing so); that is, the two measures are orthogonal, and it is possible for a task to be *urgent but not terribly important* or to be *critical but not yet pressing*.

Comment: I have a hard time getting around *urgent but not terribly important*...

Comment: @dm65: Think of a telephone ringing. It's urgent: you have about 30 seconds to take action or the opportunity will be missed. But lots of calls are not important.

Answer (score 2):

Going strictly off the dictionary definitions, urgent is "requiring immediate action" and critical is "having the potential to become disastrous" so I would say urgent is a higher priority than critical.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two is roughly the difference between time and space.

"Urgent" refers to IMMEDIATENESS (time). "Critical" refers how "central" something is (position).